# Wizard or script to assign folder permissions

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, security, file-permissions

I'm new to server support; spending most of my time in desktop support.

I've been given a request to add read-only access to a list of subfolders on a Windows 2003 Server.  Rather than adding the user into the security tab of each folder, is there a wizard or script I could use where I specify: user/folder/permissions, and click OK?

This would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start -> Programs -> Administrative Tools -> Manage your server

Second Tab: File Server

Add Shared Folders -> Next -> Assign Folder Path -> Share Name as you want, Description -> Choose Permissions as your required OR fourth Option Use Custom share and folder permission -> Finish.

Comment: Oh, I meant a specific subset of the subfolders available, not all subfolders.  Or even totally different folders.  A GUI would come in handy.  It wouldn't be a difficult application to build for a developer would it?

Comment: You can share any folder, browse that folder in wizard which one you want to share... Give it a try and let me know if any trouble.

Comment: Does it work on *multiple folder*, which is what I am seeking.  I can easily right-click on a folder in Windows Explorer and assign permissions faster than using the wizard.